# Need help in zero cross circuit by using op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, opto-isolator, phase, dimming, zero-crossing

I worked on zero crossing circuit by using opto-coupler.Circuit is
[image]

It is working okay.Zero_crossing signal is
[image]

There is a 2-3 ms of signal loss is happening with 50Hz of AC signal.I don't want more than 0.5ms signal loss something like blue color signal below.
[image]

Is there anyway that I can reduce this loss.Any use of using op-amp?

Comment: What do you mean by *2ms of signal loss*? Draw on your picture what you mean.

Comment: microcontroller is reading zero after 7-8ms only because of the signal is going to <1.5V at 7-8ms.I want micro controller to read 0 after 9.5ms.Need to change hardware like that.

Comment: That is ambiguous - Yeah I could guess what you mean but I'm not - draw it on the picture or draw a picture of what you would want to happen. Also, name the opto device and provide a link to the data sheet.

Comment: Instead of "just throwing solutions" (like opamps etc.) at this, **think** what the reason could be of this behavior. How does this circuit work? What makes the voltage go up/down. What can be done to make it go up/down faster/slower?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I can't get the sharp signal by using op-amp because of the losses of optocoupler, But I want the signal as sharp as possible.That's why asking is there any way could we reduce by using any other design.

Comment: *because of the losses of optocoupler* No, you clearly don't understand how this circuit works. *...by using any other design* You haven't even **tried** to optimize this design. What happens if you make R3 100 k instead of 10 k? Maybe R1 and R2 can have a lower value? This circuit is used quite often, you're already dismissing it while you fail to understand how it works and what can be done to change its behavior. Only if you have **good reasons** that **prove** that this circuit cannot perform as you want it to, should you dismiss it.

Comment: Do you realise that what you want is **not** a zero-crossing detector but a peak-detector? Considering the picture, you want the blue signal to be low then and only then when the AC is at its **peak**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I agree with you .This is the good circuit for zero crossing detector. For better signal by increasing forward current by changing R1,R2 we can get good signal but still there is a loss 1-1.5ms that i can't solve that exist.I want to know is there any way that i can reduce this delay.

Comment: take plots with the mains waveform on there as well, carefully, perhaps through a transformer for isolation.